# OpenOffice Calc numeric formatting language

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc

I am trying to display always-signed integers ('-1', '+4', etc: I'll even accept '+0') in OpenOffice Calc.  I've had trouble finding exact information on the numeric formatting language used.

> =TEXT(cellref;"#0")

doesn't display '+', and using "+#0" always displays '+' (it displays '-+3' for -3 in fact.)
Is there a format code for this, or do I have to write a function to handle the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short but cryptic solution:

```
=TEXT(cellref;"\+#;\-#;0")
```

This is actually a three-part format code.  It adds either a plus sign `\+#` for positive numbers, a minus sign `\-#` for negative numbers, or just a plain `0` for zeroes.

The syntax is described here: https://help.libreoffice.org/5.2/Common/Number_Format_Codes#Positive_and_Negative_Numbers

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to apply custom formatting, which is generally a good idea where numbers are involved, to make calculations with them easier:

```
"+"#;"-"#;0;General
```